# How to compare rows in groups?

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by

I have a table as following:

```
 INS_SEQ |  NAME |     DATE
-----------------------------
       1 | willy | 15/11/10
       2 |   zoe | 15/11/20
       3 | willy | 15/11/20
       4 | willy | 15/11/10
       5 | willy | 15/11/21
       6 |   zoe | 15/11/17
       7 | willy | 15/11/12
       8 |   zoe | 15/11/20
       9 |   zoe | 15/11/30
... and other values ...
```

Grouping by `NAME` column returns:

```
 INS_SEQ |  NAME |     DATE
----------------------------
       1 | willy | 15/11/10
       3 | willy | 15/11/20
       4 | willy | 15/11/10
       5 | willy | 15/11/21
       7 | willy | 15/11/12
       2 |   zoe | 15/11/20
       6 |   zoe | 15/11/17
       8 |   zoe | 15/11/20
       9 |   zoe | 15/11/30
```

I would like to get a result where for the same values `NAME` previous date is bigger than the next date (in other words I want to see those rows that satisfy the previous date of insertion is less Reg same name).
How to achieve it?

My expected output is:

```
 NAME |     DATE
-----------------
willy | 15/11/20
willy | 15/11/21
  zoe | 15/11/20
  zoe | 15/11/17
  zoe | 15/11/30
```

Comment: order by date column

Comment: but values ​​in other dates 're staying and if it does not comply with the comparison algorithm is not known how many rows take from group

Comment: What do you want to happen to rows such as your row 1 'Willy 15/11/10'?

Comment: If you're looking for each unique date to appear once per name, then use: select distinct name, date from table.  If you want it sorted, then add order by, like: order by name, date

Comment: I would like to display the rows added to the table later, which for each of the groups where the error type , the previous date is bigger than the next .

Comment: Can you put that with an example? I know you think is clear, but that `previous date is bigger than the next` sound very confussing. I update your data so you can reference each row.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First you have to write a query to find the dates which are not in order and then make sure you don't include the last record of same name.

```
-- Finding dates which are not in order
(SELECT * FROM CompareRows  C1 WHERE EXISTS 
   (SELECT * FROM CompareRows  C2 
     WHERE C2.ID < C1.ID
       AND C2.OrderDate < C1.OrderDate
       AND C2.Name = C1.Name))

 EXCEPT
 -- Not including last record with same name
(SELECT C1.*
FROM CompareRows C1 LEFT JOIN CompareRows C2
 ON (C1.name = C2.name AND C1.ID < C2.ID)
WHERE C2.ID IS NULL)
```

Here is the live demo
http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/51865/1/0

Comment: and got in the second column lines sorted by groups and I want to get the lines do not fit into the scheme where someone inserts rows of old data from the previous date on the same group , I should give you other columns so that you may understand what it is I will try tomorrow when I will have access to look at other column of the table and make an example

Comment: @wsmx , it would help if you provide more info tomorrow

Comment: OK, thanks very much for yours interest , my question is not full , propably there is a key that identifies inserts one after the other And i need to group the names and then compare the somehow after the dates which were earlier key

Comment: I uppdate data in question.

Comment: If that's the requirement your output should not have Zoe 15/11/17 and Zoe 15/11/30 as their previous date is not bigger than next date. Does that sound good?